# Difference between NE555 and NE555xx

Tags: integrated-circuit, 555

I'm going to order the NE555 chip from Texas Instruments ([Link](http://ti.com)) to build a circuit, but they only have NE555P, NE555DR etc. Can I use the NE555xx instead of NE555? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 6):

The difference is in the packages. The function is the same. You can search for package types on TI page, they have nice documentation. [Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf)

As you can see, in NE555`xx`, the `xx` represent a different package type. There is more information about these `xx` on pages 20-22 inside the datasheet. The letters NE/SA/NA/SE before the 555 represent slightly different manufacturing processes & part QA, corresponding mostly to safe operating temperature ranges (commercial, industrial, automotive, military) & voltages. You need to  read the datasheet and select the chip which is appropriate for you.

[image]
[image: info]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC#Derivatives - as you can easily see, 555 timers variations naming ain't limited to this single datasheet; only `NE/SA/NA/SE` prefixes are related to temperatures (com,ind,auto&mil) - of the most common ones, `LMC` is the CMOS version, `TLC` is the LinCMOS one, there's also `TS`/`CSS` (low power versions), a very common `LM` (different manufacturing process & internals AFAIR) & some other versions I can't recall of the top of my head.

Answer (score 3):

Extra letters at the end of a part number usually specify the package, operating temperature range, quality level, or other such information. For the NE555, the list of part numbers is in chapter 12 of the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf) in the Packaging Information table. For example, the NE555P is an 8-pin PDIP package rated for 0-70C. There's also information on lead finish, Pb-free/RoHS, package quantities, and moisture sensitivity level. Pick the parameters that matter to go and go with the cheapest part number that provides them.